# What do multiple, consecutive fat arrows in method parameters mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I understand that a method can have code like this:

```
def m(p1:Int => Int) ...
```

Which means this method takes a function p1 that returns an Int

But while browsing the Play! framework code i found a trait with indecipherable methods:

```
trait Secured {

  def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get(Security.username)

  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Auth.login)

  def withAuth(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action(request => f(user)(request))
    }
  }

  /**
   * This method shows how you could wrap the withAuth method to also fetch your user
   * You will need to implement UserDAO.findOneByUsername
   */
  def withUser(f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
    UserDAO.findOneByUsername(username).map { user =>
      f(user)(request)
    }.getOrElse(onUnauthorized(request))
  }
}
```

[Play! Scala Security](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaSecurity)

What does the `f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result` mean? At first glance it looks like a method that returns a function `r` of type Request; `r` then returns a `Result`.

Is this the right assumption?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What does the f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result mean? At first glance it looks like a method that returns a function r of type Request; r then returns a Result.

`f` returns a function of type `Request[AnyContent] => Result`, i.e. a function that takes a `Request[AnyContent]` and returns a `Result`.

In other words `f` is a curried function. You could call it as `f(user)(request)` to get back a `Result`.

Comment: Ok, cool. But why does this need to be specified? Why can't the compiler infer the type that `Request` returns? Edit: nevermind, i suppose subtypes of Request could return different types of Results, so this is helpful.

Comment: @CameronA.Ellis I'm not quite sure I understand your comment. The `Request` object does not return anything. The function returned by `f`, which has type `Request[AnyContent] => Result` returns a `Result`. The return type can not be left out of a function's type because then it would look like `f` returned a `Request` object - not a function that takes a `Request` object, which is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

`def withAuth(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result)` means, that `f` is a by-name parameter, and you can write something like this:

```
withAuth {
  logger.info("Here we go")
  ...
  chooseTheAction("list")
}
```

where `chooseTheAction` takes a `String` and returns a function performing a request, `Request[AnyContent] => Result`