# How to implement the following code snippet of scala in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am implementing a code to dynamically add multiple columns to a Dataframe with null values in row

I found the following code snippet in scala where the map function of Dataframe object is used.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataTypes, NullType, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Encoders, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;

def addColumnsViaMap(df: DataFrame, words: List[String]): DataFrame = {
   val encoder = RowEncoder.apply(getSchema(df, words))
   df.map(mappingRows(df.schema)(words))(encoder)
}

private val mappingRows: StructType => List[String] => Row => Row =
  (schema) => (words) => (row) => {
     val addedCols: List[Any] = words.map(_=> null)
    Row.merge(row, Row.fromSeq(addedCols))
  }

private def getSchema(df: DataFrame, words: List[String]): StructType = {
  var schema: StructType = df.schema
  words.foreach(word => schema = schema.add(word, "string", false))
  schema
}
```

I have implemented the following two functions in java

```
 private StructType getSchema(Dataset<Row> df, List<String> cols){
        StructType schema = df.schema();
        cols.forEach(col -> schema.add(col, "int", true));
        return schema;
    }

private addColumnsViaMap(Dataset<Row> df, List<String> cols){
    Encoder<Row> encoder1 = 
  RowEncoder.apply(dataConsolidationEngine.getSchema(df,cols));
   df.map(new MapFunction<Set<String>, Row>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Row call(Set<String> cols) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }, encoder1);
}
```

The addColumnsViaMap method has compilation error connot resolve anonymous map function method due to the parameters mismatch.

and i dont understand the scala code of mappingRows especially the following `StructType => List[String] => Row => Row =
  (schema) => (words) => (row)` what this means ??

and how to implement the above scala code in Java ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do multiple, consecutive fat arrows in method parameters mean in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013133/what-do-multiple-consecutive-fat-arrows-in-method-parameters-mean-in-scala)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this declaration is a bit complex (and IMO a bit unreadable too), so let's step back.

In scala, `String`, `List`... are types everyone knows of. You can make a variable of type `String`.

What you can also do, is assign a function to a variable (this is the functionnal orientation of scala), so functions also have types. Say for example, if you have a function that takes a `List` and outputs a `String`, it is of type `List => String`.

And does that look like in code ?

```
// A list of strings
val names = List("alice", "bob")
// A function that takes a list and returns a string
def listToString(list: List[String]): String = list.mkString(",")
// We can assign the function to a variable
val myListToString: List[String] => String = listToString
```

But we have a shorter notation for declaring functions, we may declare them "inline", without using a `def` statement. So that the above code can be equivalently written :

```
val names = List("alice", "bob")
val myListToString: List[String] => String = (list) => list.mkString(",")
```

So, generically speaking :

- `A => B` is a *type*, of a function that takes an `A` and returns a `B`
- `(arg: A) => { new B() }` is an actual function that takes an instance of `A` as input (the instance being bound to the variable name `arg` and whose body returns an instance of B

Now let's do something crazy, let's... start over. Say that `F` is a function that takes a `List` and returns a `String`. What would a function that takes an `Int` and return a `F` look like ?

Well it would be :

- `Int => F`.
- That is to say : `Int => (List => String)`
- Which can be written `Int => List => String`

And how do you declare it ?

```
// Borrowing from above
val names = List("alice", "bob")
val myListToString: List[String] => String = (list) => list.mkString(",")
// now we're doing it
val intToListToString = (integerValue) => myListToString
// now we're doing it in one go
val intToListToString2 = (integerValue) => (list) => list.mkString(",")
```

Here, `intToListToString` is a function that takes an `int` and returns "a function that takes a `List` and returns a `String`".

And you can nest again, and again.

Until you get : `StructType => List[String] => Row => Row` which is a type that means "a function that takes a `StructType` as input and returns (a function that takes a `List[String]`as input and returns (a function that takes a `Row`as input and returns a row)).

And you could implement it as :

```
(schema) => // a function that takes schema, and returns
    (words) => // a function that takes a list of words and returns
        (row) => // a function that takes a row and returns
            Row.fromSeq(...) // another row
```

Now what would that look like in Java ?

If you want to convert it strictly as it is, you may think about it this way : the natural equivalent of scala's `A => B` is `java.util.Function<A, B>`. On top of it, if you want to use a function to do a Spark `map` operation on a `Dataframe`, you have to use a `MapFunction<>`.

So we are looking to implement a `Function<Schema, Function<List<String>, MapFunction<Row, Row>>>` or something of the sort.

Using java lambda notation, you can do it this way :

```
schema ->  words -> row -> Row.merge(row, Row.fromSeq(Array.newInstance(String.class, words.size)))
```

Which is a function that takes a schema,

- that returns a function that takes a list of word

  - that returns a function that takes a Row

    - that returns a row augmented with columns containing null

Maybe my java syntax is correct, maybe not I do not know.

What I do know is that it is a vastly too complex way of achieving your requirements.

What is this requirement : you have a dataframe, you have a list of words, you want to create new columns with this name and containing null.

So what I would have done in scala is this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def addColumnsViaMap(dataframe: DataFrame, words: List[String]) = words.foldLeft(dataframe)((df, word) => df.withColumn(word, lit(null: String)))

val dataframe = Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d")).toDF("columnA", "columnB")
val words = List("columnC", "columnD")
addColumnsViaMap(dataframe, words).show

+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|columnA|columnB|columnC|columnD|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      a|      b|   null|   null|
|      c|      d|   null|   null|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Which you can probably write in java as such

```
DataFrame addColumnsViaMap(DataFrame dataframe, List<String> words) {
    for (String word: words) {
        dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(word, lit((String) null))
    }
    return dataframe;
}
```

Once again, I do not have a Java based spark environment, but my point is : if you get the principle, rewritting is simple.

Comment: Thanks that helps, now i understand the scala code clearly. Now that if i have to implement 3 MapFunction methods in one single statement, its lot more confusing and difficult to implement. Could you please help me to break the above scala code to 3 separate map functions. So that i can try to implement in java as 3 separate map functions.

Comment: @vkumar22 you do not **have to** write it as 3 separate functions. Though you probably can. First : I've rewritten it all in *one line* of scala that does not involve any nesting of functions.  Second : having functions that return functions 3 level deep is not natural in Java (possible ? yes, natural ? not so much). Scala being functionnally oriented is more natural for this. But it could just as easily be written as a single function that takes 3 arguments in both languages, instead of a curried version (3 functions taking one argument each). If you undertand it, you can convert it.

Comment: Thanks !! Yes, i wanted to follow that approach of adding the new columns initially. But i found in the link https://lansalo.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/ where they have explained that solution is not so performance/memory efficient. So i wanted to follow the other efficient approach.

Comment: But what are they measuring ? They are measuring the time spent declaring the dataframe. Surely the time spent creating a dataframe is **ridiculously** dwarfed by the computation that it involves. Who cares if declaring the computation takes 400 **millli** seconds instead of 70. Surely you are not running a spark cluster for a computation whose order of magnitude is in the milli seconds ball-park ? Have you actually measured ?

Answer (score 0):

```scala
private val mappingRows: StructType => List[String] => Row => Row =
  (schema) => (words) => (row) => {
     val addedCols: List[Any] = words.map(_=> null)
    Row.merge(row, Row.fromSeq(addedCols))
  }
```

Simply put, that could be read as :

`mappingRows` is a 'function' that takes 3 parameters (of types `StructType`, `List` and `Row`, say schema, words and row) and that returns a `Row`. But instead of calling it like that :

```scala
mappingRows(schema, words, row)`
```

you will go

```scala
mappingRows(schema)(words)(row)
```

This means that calling just

```scala
mappingRows(schema)(words)
```

will return a function that take a `Row` and returns a `Row` : a mapping function that you can pass to the typical `.map()` function.

Basically, given a schema and a list of col names, the closure takes a row as input. It simply adds on null column to that row for each given col name.

Does it help you answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.   If you look at the  following code ``` def addColumnsViaMap(df: DataFrame, words: List[String]): DataFrame = {
   val encoder = RowEncoder.apply(getSchema(df, words))
   df.map(mappingRows(df.schema)(words))(encoder)
}
```  The mappingRows is called with only two parameters schema and words, but row is not passed to it. how is row accessed inside that ?

Comment: @vkumar22 yes it is called with only two params : schema and words : that will return a function that takes a `Row` and returns a `Row` : a mapping function, that you can pass to the `map()` function ... Got it ? I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for providing more details, i got it. Let me see if i can try that in java